# INNER JOIN to more than one table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have four tables

```
student
-------
id, int
firstName, varchar
lastName, varchar

course
------
id, int
name, varchar

semester
--------
id, int
name, varchar

mark
----
studentId, int
courseId, int
semesterId, int
mark, int
```

I want to make a sql query that retrives `firstName`, `lastName`, `courseName`, `semesterName` and `mark` for every row in the `mark` table.

I tried to do it with INNER JOIN but I can't make INNER JOIN for more than one table.

That code I reached finally

```
select student.firstName, student.lastName, course.name, semester.name, mark.mark
from mark
INNER JOIN student ON student.id = mark.studentId
INNER JOIN course ON course.id = mark.courseId
INNER JOIN semester ON semester.id = mark.semesterId
```

Comment: that should work.. what sql are you using ? mysql/ ms-sql-server ? are you sure there are data in the tables with correct ids ?

Comment: show me your table structure...

Comment: What do you mean with *you can't*?

Comment: this works perfectly, whats wrong?

Comment: I don't see a problem with your query. Note that with an inner join, if there isn't a corresponding row in the join, the record will be thrown out. In other words, if a mark is missing a student, course, and/or semester, that mark will not be returned.

Comment: thank you for replies ...

@GabyakaG.Petrioli, I use MS Access DB and I use this query in Data Source Object in Web developer .net 2008

Comment: @Learner, I but my table sturcture in my post :)

Comment: "I can't make INNER JOIN for more than one table" - that is really strange. Try to list tables in FROM clause and join conditions in WHERE clause.

Comment: @Mulmoth, I mean that when I make INNER JOIN to one table it works , but when try INNER JOIN to more than one table it dosen't work

Comment: In MS Access, you need to use parenthesises for each joined table, like "from (mark
INNER JOIN student ON student.id = mark.studentId)
INNER JOIN course ON course.id = mark.courseId" etc.

Comment: @HackedByChinese, all my rows in mark table are complete :)

Comment: @Arvo, opsss it works for tow tables, what I should do for third table ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ms Access you have to include parentheses in a query with multiple joins:

```
select st.firstName, st.lastName, c.name, sm.name, m.mark
from (((mark m
        INNER JOIN student st ON st.id = m.studentId)
        INNER JOIN course c ON c.id = m.courseId)
        INNER JOIN semester sm ON sm.id = m.semesterId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try theta style join:

```
select student.firstName, student.lastName, course.name, semester.name, mark.mark
from mark, student ,course, semester
WHERE  student.id = mark.studentId AND course.id = mark.courseId AND semester.id = mark.semesterId
```

Comment: That's strange, because I've tested it on Access DB (2003) and it works.