# Inner Join of more than one table in C# with SQLite

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I need to do an Inner Join with more than one table in my C# program.

I've tried to execute my query using DBeaver in the same database, and it works. 
But when I use that same query in my C# code, it returns nothing. I know the connection works, since I get data from one of the tables, and that does fill. Also, it did work just doing one inner join.
I use the SQLite NuGet Package.

This is my query (the one I used in DBeaver):

```sql
SELECT mcc.ModeloId, t.FctrlClusterId, mcc.FctrlClusterDescription, cl.ClusterId, cl.ClusterName, 
t.Command, co.CommandName, t.AttributeId, at.AttributeName, t.DataPosition, t.DataType, t.TramaData
FROM Trama t
INNER JOIN ModeloClusterCanal mcc ON t.FctrlClusterId = mcc.FctrlClusterId 
INNER JOIN Cluster cl ON mcc.ClusterId = cl.ClusterId
INNER JOIN Command co ON t.Command = co.CommandId
INNER JOIN Attribute at ON t.AttributeId = at.AttributeId
WHERE RxTx LIKE 'Tx'
```

And this is my C# code (with the same query, but using `String.Format()`):

```cs
private static readonly string tablaCluster = "Cluster";
private static readonly string tablaCommand = "Command";
private static readonly string tablaAttribute = "Attribute";
private static readonly string tablaModeloClusterCanal = "ModeloClusterCanal";
private static readonly string tablaTrama = "Trama";

CommandText = String.Format("SELECT mcc.ModeloId, t.FctrlClusterId, mcc.FctrlClusterDescription, cl.ClusterId, cl.ClusterName, t.Command, " +
    "co.CommandName, t.AttributeId, at.AttributeName, t.DataPosition, t.DataType, t.TramaData " +
    "FROM {0} t " +
    "INNER JOIN {1} mcc ON t.FctrlClusterId = mcc.FctrlClusterId " +
    "INNER JOIN {2} cl ON mcc.ClusterId = cl.ClusterId " +
    "INNER JOIN {3} co ON t.Command = co.CommandId " +
    "INNER JOIN \"{4}\" at ON t.AttributeId = at.AttributeId " +
    "WHERE t.RxTx LIKE 'Tx'", 
    tablaTrama,
    tablaModeloClusterCanal,
    tablaCluster,
    tablaCommand,
    tablaAttribute);

    SqliteAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, SqliteConnection);
    SqliteAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "TramasTx");
```

*(before this code, I open the connection and fill the DataSet with another table)*

I also tried using the query string directly, without formatting it, but it gave the same result.

In DBeaver, I get the desired columns and the rows I want.

In C#, the `Table` with which I fill the `DataSet` has 0 rows.

I tried using parenthesis as said in [INNER JOIN to more than one table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617840/inner-join-to-more-than-one-table), but it didn't work either.
I really can't see what can cause this.

In case the ER diagram of the DB could help, I can edit the question and add it.

---

**EDIT:** I edited the CommandText since I left some parenthesis that shouldn't be there, and I also tried resetting the SqliteCommand variable (because I used it before, with another command), but this didn't work either. I'm gonna try using another variable for the SQLiteCommand, since I don't know if reusing it could affect the result?

---

**EDIT2:** I wasn't using at all the SQLiteCommand variable so got rid of it. I tried disposing of the SQLiteAdapter (since I do use it for the table data I get before), but it didn't work either.
It doesn't give me any error or exception, it just creates the Table inside the DataSet, but the row count is 0.

---

**EDIT3:** I couldn't find the problem with the query. I talked with a colleage and they told me that, since the query works on programs like DBeaver, it might be because the driver in .NET works different. In the end I just collected each table in different DataTables and got the info I needed iterating and using if control statements. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Those are **not** the same query as you'll see if you print out `CommandText` in your program. Start by getting rid of all those parentheses.

Comment: My bad, I edited the query following the post I mentioned just before posting this and didn't edit it back. I tried using the same query (AFAK, I might have mispelled something, but I was pretty sure) and it didn't work either. I'll try it again and edit it once I know it doesn't work for sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old question, and I think I didn't find an appropriate answer, but I'm copy-pasting my last EDIT since it seems that it's the way I resolved my issue.

> I couldn't find the problem with the query. I talked with a colleage and they told me that, since the query works on programs like DBeaver, it might be because the driver in .NET works different. In the end I just collected each table in different DataTables and got the info I needed iterating and using if control statements.

I'm marking this as my answer but won't close the post, in case someone finds the real issue at some point.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 issues

1. Why you used inverted quotes in table name (`Attribute`) remove the quotes.
2. In where clause add alias or table name before column name `WHERE table.RxTx LIKE 'Tx'"`

Hope this will help full for you

Comment: Double quotes quote identifier names (tables and columns) and while not needed here because Attribute isn't a sqlite keyword, is harmless.

Comment: I used double quotes because DBeaver indicated "Attribute" as a keyword, and I thought it was. Thank you for telling me! I'll also try adding the alias in RxTx!